# multidimensional arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

If i have the following:

```
$a = array();
```

and then want to use its elements in an update query i have been recommended to do as follows:

```
foreach($a as $value) {

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tb SET username = '$value'");

}
```

However what do i do if i have many arrays and want to use the one element of each in the update?

Say...

```
$a = array();
$b = array();
$c = array();

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tb SET username = 'element of a', image = 'element of b', address = 'element of c'...");
```

How would i use the foreach to achieve this.  I am aware i could do:

```
$d = array($a, $b, $c)
```

But if this is any help forward i don't know.

Thanks in advance for shedding any light on the problem...

Comment: Did you want to update every c for every b for every a (ie: inner loop) or are these arrays of a parallel structure, where an element in a has a corresponding element in b which has one in c which leads to one update for a given index?

Comment: The latter case.  a,b and c are corresponding elements

Comment: Got it.  Steve just answered your question.  To his answer, I'd add that $array_Length would be the length of your array (eg: count($a)) and please make sure that $a,$b and $c have the same number of elements.

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop.

Example:

```
for($i=0; $i<$array_Length; $i++)
{
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE tb SET username = '$a[$i], image = '$b[$i]',  address = '$c[$i]'...");
}
```

$i is the counter, and you just loop through however many elements are in one array (You stated they all correspond to eachother), then pull out the same element number from each array.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same index in all arrays, you could use

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value)
{ 
    // do sth. with $value
    // do sth with $b[$key]
}
```

This is  similar to Steves answer, but his requireds the keys to be ints beginning from 0 with no gaps, where this will also work if your keys are strings or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, PHP 5.5 [will support unpacking multidimensional arrays in `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#control-structures.foreach.list), but it's highly unlikely that's an option for you.  You'll have to stick with an ordinary `for` loop *assuming* all three lists are the same length and have the same keys:

```
$length = min(count($a), count($b), count($c));
for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
   $query = "UPDATE tb SET username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($a[$x]) ...
}
```

If you're worried about the arrays not having the same keys, you can use `array_values` on each of them first.

---

I'll also give the usual speach about how you shouldn't use `mysql_*` and should upgrade to `PDO` or `mysqli`, both of which would make this a bit easier for you:

```
$query = "UPDATE tb SET username = ?, image = ?, address = ?";
$pdo = new PDO;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
   $stmt->execte(array(a[$x], $b[$x], $c[$x]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both three `array` has same size. Then Use `for` loop and update on every icremented `key` value.

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++):

       $option1=$a[$i];
       $option2=$b[$i];
       $option3=$c[$i];         

    endfor;
```